# why does pointer to member conversion from base to derived gives error

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, pointer-to-member

If conversion from pointer to Base member To pointer to Derived class member is valid, why does the following code fails to compile

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun1()
    {
        cout<<"fun1 in Base"<<endl;
    }
};

class Der
{
public:
    void fun1()
    {
        cout<<"fun1 in Der"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    void (Der::*funptr)() = &Base::fun1;
}
```

Compiler gives an error saying

> error: cannot convert 'void (Base::*)()' to 'void (Der::*)()' in initialization|

Comment: Because they're different types? Polymorphism applies to the objects themselves, not the member functions.

Comment: I'm interested in how someone who is more of a language lawyer can explain it tho.

Comment: @Troy: Pointers to members obey the laws of *contravariance*. What the OP says about the conversion being valid is true. The code is written without paying proper attention though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `Der` is not derived from `Base`. Your classes are unrelated. There's no inheritance relationship between them.

If you indeed define your `Der` as a descendant of `Base`

```
class Der : public Base
{
   ...
```

the code will compile.

The compiler cannot magically guess that you wanted to derive your `Der` from `Base`. You are supposed to remember to explicitly tell the compiler about it.